# What cooking gadget is that?

Tags: equipment

I was watching youtube vids about cooking and I saw [this Gordon Ramsay one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KR44a_5v_A) about broccoli soup. Around the 56 second mark to the right of the broccoli on the table is an elevated piece of metal with holes in it. What is it?

[image]

So far I'm thinking some kind of weird large grater or a popcorn sifter. Can anyone help?

Comment: (plus one for "popcorn sifter")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simply a built-in vent for the built-in appliances integrated within his commercial kitchen table.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that is the ventilation for the range, rather than a kitchen utensil.